# Different behavior while passing argument through Thread().start() vs lambda expression in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda, arguments

I have created one function named printInteger() as

```
static void printInteger(object i)
{
    Console.Write(i + " ");
}
```

I am creating 10 threads using a for loop and passing integer as an argument via two methods.
**First Method** : passing argument through start()

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
     new Thread(printInteger).Start(i);
}
```

Output in this case is : `1 2 3 5 0 4 6 8 7 9`

**Second Method** : passing argument through Lambda expression

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{                          
     new Thread(() =>printInteger(i)).Start();
}
```

Output in this case is : `2 4 3 4 5 7 8 8 9 10`

**Behaviour first** : As thread will execute in any order, so non
   increasing order of the Integers is expected.

**Behavior second** : As i variable refers to the same memory location throughout the loop’s lifetime, so it is also expected that value of i might change during
   runtime.
**My Question is:**
 - Why the result in First Method and the Second Method is different?
 - We can see both the methods are behaving as a Behavior first. But why only the second method behaving as a Behavior second?

Comment: It's really unclear to me what you mean by "We can see both the methods are behaving as a Behavior first."

Comment: @JonSkeet the output in both methods are in non-increasing order as thread can execute in any order.

Comment: (The underlying cause for this behaviour has been explained in answers to many different questions, but I *tend* to answer rather than closing as a duplicate as it's a tricky topic to find - the more variations that are available, the more likely it is that other users will find them... and with a direct answer addressing the exact code.)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. (I skimmed too quickly the first time.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for the quick response. :)

Comment: @Jon: _"more variations that are available, the more likely it is that other users will find them"_ -- we don't need variations on _answers_ to make duplicates easier to find. "Sign post" duplicate questions, closed as such, work just fine for that. In any case, I fail to see how the answer you posted below is materially different from [the one you wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/271447) almost a decade ago.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: They can make the answers easier to understand though. In this case, it's specifically about `Thread.Start` evaluating the argument immediately; anyone in the same situation is likely to find this answer more helpful than the ones on duplicates. I don't have strong opinions on this, and for *most* topics I agree with you - variable capture feels slightly different to a lot of topics due to being a bit subtle, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why the result in First Method and the Second Method is different?

Because in the first approach you're passing the *value* of `i` to the `Thread.Start` method as its initial state. That is evaluated at the time you call `Start`.

In the second approach, you're *capturing* `i` in your lambda expression. It's evaluated at the point of execution. All your threads will refer to the same variable, and print out the value of the variable *at the time they execute*.

If you want to use a lambda expression but have each thread capture a different variable, simply introduce a new variable inside the loop:

```
// I've renamed the method it calls to be more idiomatic
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // Each iteration creates a separate "copy" variable
    int copy = i;
    new Thread(() => PrintInt32(copy)).Start();
}
```